# Inject service into the entity before deserialization

Tags: jmsserializerbundle

I'm looking for a way to inject certain services into the entity that is being deserialized with jms serializer. The reason being that I'm using the serializer's accessor method which I will required certain services to be injected to do the deserialization.

Comment: I ended up using the serialization event to modify the data but still very interested to know the solution to inject to accessor method